# CSV file formatting – start a new row after every nth entry

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently trying to organize data collected by a web scraper into a .csv file. The data is collected in a list and then written as csv.

My problem is that the program is writing the data into a single row in the file.

How can I tell the program to start a new row after for example every fifth entry?

Here is what my code looks like right now:

```
import csv

csvFile = open('practive.csv', 'w+')

try:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerow(('kaufpreis', 'ort', 'wohnfläche','zimmer', 'company'))
    writer.writerows([dataliste])
finally:
    csvFile.close()
```

Comment: Don't put `dataliste` inside another list. It's already a list.

Comment: You might want to use `with` context management instead of `try... finally` - it's more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

Split your list into chunks of 5 elements, using one of the techniques in [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks).

Then write the chunked list to the CSV file.

```
writer.writerows(chunks(dataliste, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how you are giving data to the writer

```
import csv
csvFile = open('practive.csv', 'w+')
dataliste = [[1,2,3,4,5], [11,22,33,44,55]]
try:
   writer = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=',')
   writer.writerow(('kaufpreis', 'ort', 
   'wohnfläche','zimmer', 'company'))
   writer.writerows(data for data in dataliste)
finally:
   csvFile.close()
```